# Updating opportunity when opportunity is won

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've got the task of updating a CRM plugin for a system migrating from cm 2013 to 2016. The plugin fails because it tries to set the opportunity state to won, simply by updating the field. And you need to use the WinOpporunityRequest to do so.

The logic is as follows:

1. When the opportunity is won the plugin executes and runs on the opportunityclose entity
2. The plugin creates a new custom entity record (project) and updates several other records.
3. It gets the current opportunity by using the opportunityid of the opportunityclose entity
4. It updates a field on the opportunity with a reference to the newly created project record.
5. That update is done through the Update() method.

On 5 it fails because when at 3 it gets the current opportunity it already has the state of won. And if you try to update the record with a new state it fails.

My question is, how can I get the opportunity when acting on the opportunityclose entity and update only the one single field. I do not need to set the state as this is done in the standard CRM flow.

--Edit
The line of code that fetches the opportunity:

```
Xrm.Opportunity currentOpportunityObjectToUpdate = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Xrm.Opportunity>().First(x => x.Id == entityRef.Id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform allows you to update closed opportunities, I just tried it to verify.  What is the error you are getting?

In step #5, make sure you're only sending the attributes you're trying to update (opportunityid and lookup to project).  So, when you issue the update, don't use any preexisting opportunity object that you either retrieved or created...doing so sends all attributes that are on the object and the platform will process each attribute as if it were being changed even if the value is unchanged. Instead, create a new opportunity object with just the id and project specified, something like this:

```
context.AddObject(new Opportunity() { 
    Id = idOfOpportunity,            // you may have to specify id both here...
    OpportunityId = idOfOpportunity, // ...and here, can never remember. Doesn't hurt to specify in both places.
    new_ProjectId = idOfProject
}); 
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

If you get stuck, you always have an easy workaround option: take the logic from #4 and move it to an async plugin on create of project (even a workflow should work).

Comment: I've added the line of code that gets the opportunity. Here it has the status of won. I'm looking into how to update only the one property. There I'm a bit stuck. As far is I know I need to get the record from CRM, update the single property and update the record. Since getting the record from CRM has the status set to won, it will update that property as well

Comment: Is this caused by the stage it's in? Namely PostOperation?

Comment: I updated my answer. Without knowing what the specific error is, I can't say for sure if it's related to being in PostOperation.

Comment: The error says I need to use the WinOpporunityRequest to close the opportunity. But the sample you gave is exactly wat I am looking for. I didn't know for sure if that was possible, as all examples I could find were retreiving the record form CRM.

Comment: I've tried this, but when I do addobject it will give an error on inserting a duplicate. And when I change it to UpdateObject, it will give an error that the context is not tracking changes.

Comment: You need to set the mergeoption on your context. Check out [Do you understand MergOptions?](https://www.develop1.net/public/post/Do-you-understand-MergeOptions.aspx) for a very clear explanation.

Comment: I solved it by doing a service.Retreive() call and passing in no attributes for the columnset option. Then I could call the service.Update() on that record. Thanks for the link though, that's new to me.